# Variable length array of non-POD element type 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') c++

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode, string, xcode4

I get this error in my c++ code Variable length array of non-POD element type `string` (aka `basic_string<char>`).

```
string words[numWords];
```

If I get rid of numWords and enter a number this works fine but if i put the same number in a variable it gives me the `Variable length array of non-POD element type 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char>')` error, I have done it this way before and it worked in visual studio but I have now tried it in Xcode and it doesn't work. I have tried using vectors but I can't get them sot store any data and they just come back blank.

For those who asked this is my vector code should all be there

```
char ch;

ifstream repFile("//Users//bobthemac//Documents//c++asignment//c++asignment//test1.txt");

while(repFile.get(ch))
{
    if(ch == ' ' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\t')
    {
        numWords++;
    }
}

vector<string> words (numWords);

while(repFile >> x)
    words.push_back(x);
repFile.close();
```

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with Xcode. It has to do with the compiler you're using. Some version of gcc I presume? What does `gcc -version` say?

Comment: Can you post your `vector` code?

Comment: Using a variable for the size of an array is not standard.  Using a vector<string> should work, so the real issue is finding why that doesn't work for you.

Comment: gcc -version says no input files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable length arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c)

Comment: @bobthemac: lrfy meant to ask what `gcc --version` (two hyphens) says.

Comment: @bobthemac See my answer and try upgrading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This initializes `words` with `numWords` empty strings then appends the actual strings afterwards:

```
vector<string> words (numWords);

while(repFile >> x)
    words.push_back(x);
```

Change to:

```
vector<string> words;

while(repFile >> x)
    words.push_back(x);
```

or:

```
vector<string> words (numWords);

int idx = 0;
while(repFile >> x /* && idx < numWords */)
    words[idx++] = x;
```

EDIT:

There is no reason to count the number of words before populating the `vector`:

```
vector<string> words;
ifstream repFile("//Users//bobthemac//Documents//c++asignment//c++asignment//test1.txt");
if (repFile.is_open())
{
    while(repFile >> x)
    {
        words.push_back(x);
    }
    repFile.close();
}
```

Comment: I have tried both of your solutions but one throws an exception and the other still just prints nothing, think it might be my computer or a daft mistake

Comment: I think you need to reopen `repFile` before the second `while`.

Comment: Thanks that got it i had to close repFile and then open it again thanks for all the help from everyone.

Comment: Why the extra copy in your code example. `while(repFile >> words[idx++]) {}`

Comment: @LokiAstari, oversight. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

C++ doesn't have C99-style variable length arrays.  Your compiler might support them as an extension, but they're not part of the language.  In this specific case, your success with Visual Studio indicates that it does in fact have such an extension.  clang++ will support VLAs, but only of POD types, so your attempt to make a VLA of `string` objects won't work. g++ does work on my machine if I leave off enough warning/error flags.

Comment: Or it may just be that the dynamic value was used to initialise a `const int` and VS failed to spot that the value didn't originate statically, in order to warn/error. I've seen it happen.

Comment: Could be.  I know approximately nothing about Visual Studio.

Comment: Well I've seen it in GCC too. Far more likely than accidentally using an extension, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you need to write `gcc --version` to get the version.

As others state, you *shouldn't* use variable-length arrays, but GCC does support them as an extension in C++. My GCC 4.4.4 compiles just fine with the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  string s[n];
  return 0;
}
```

Does that code compile for you? If it does, then you need to give us the smallest piece of code that fails.

The best solution, though, is to use `vector<string>`.